# Use magic methods to access object with integer ID

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I have an instance of a product object:

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
```

Here is a sample from the product object

```
["media_gallery_images"]=>
object(Varien_Data_Collection)#405 (13) {
  ["_items":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    object(Varien_Object)#394 (7) {
      ["_data":protected]=>
      array(11) {
        ["value_id"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["file"]=>
        string(17) "/h/a/image.jpg"
        ["label"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["position"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["disabled"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["label_default"]=>
        NULL
        ["position_default"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["disabled_default"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["url"]=>
        string(66) "http://domain.domain.domain/media/catalog/product/h/a/image.jpg"
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["path"]=>
        string(73) "/home/domain/public_html/magento/media/catalog/product/h/a/image.jpg"
      }
      ["_hasDataChanges":protected]=>
      bool(false)
      ["_origData":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["_idFieldName":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["_isDeleted":protected]=>
      bool(false)
      ["_oldFieldsMap":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["_syncFieldsMap":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to access the "url" inside the object Varien_Object identified by 1 inside the object Varien_Data_Collection identified by "media_gallery_images". This seems easy enough, right?

```
$url = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages()->get1()->getUrl();
```

This echos an error into my source:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method Varien_Data_Collection::get1() in <b>[filepath]
```

So I'm getting halfway there, but the magic method get1() isn't working. I don't know enough about how these methods work to understand why.

How I access the element that I want to access (["url"])?

## SPECIFIC SOLUTION EDIT

Okay so this works specifically for the url

```
$url = chop($_product->getMediaConfig()->getMediaUrl($_product->getMediaGallery('images')['file']), "/")  . $_product->getImage();
```

But honestly there has to be a way to do it how I was trying to originally. That "general" solution would save me from running into problems with this further in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I don't know how nobody could answer this, but I found this solution after I went back to it with a better understanding of magic methods. Here is the solution.

```
$url = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItems()[$_product->getId()]->getUrl();
```

Notice that _items can be accessed with getItems(), then treated as the array that it is. In the example shown above, the product id was 1 (hence the get1() I originally tried).

Answer (score 1):

To add to [the accepted answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/120026/14992), the solution works because `Varien_Data_Collection::getItems()` returns an array.

You could also loop `$product->getMediaGalleryImages()` until you find the index you're looking for, since `Varien_Data_Collection` implements [`IteratorAggregate`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php), and its [`getIterator()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php#L736-L743) method returns an `ArrayIterator` of it's items (array):

```
# File: /lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php
/**
 * Implementation of IteratorAggregate::getIterator()
 */
public function getIterator()
{
    $this->load();
    return new ArrayIterator($this->_items);
}
```

Also useful is the [`->getItemById()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php#L721-L734) method on the collection to return a specific item from the collection:

```
$url = $product->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemById($product->getId())->getUrl();
```